# Каким способом можно добавить в базу данных строки используя цикл?

Tags: php, html, mysql, while

Пользователь должен создать *стол* на N участников, которые будут потом заполнять его, но при создании надо создать N пронумерованных строк, делаю как-то так:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div style="max-width: 500px; margin: auto; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9); padding: 10pt; border-radius: 15pt; " class=".col-md-4">
        <input type="text" name="num_of_members">
        <button class="btn" name="create_table">create</button>


    </div>
</form>

function create_t($num, $num_of_members){
    $mysqli = $GLOBALS['mysqli'];
    $mysqli -> query("CREATE TABLE `mybase`.`lottery_$num` ( `num` INT(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `members` INT(16) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`num`), UNIQUE (`members`)) ENGINE = MyISAM;");
    $mysqli -> query("UPDATE `num` SET  `num_t` =  `num_t` + 1");
    $i = 0;
    while ($i <= $num_of_members) {
        $i++;
        $success = $mysqli -> query("INSERT INTO `mybase`.`lottery_$num` (`num`) VALUES ('$i');");
        echo $success;
    }
if (isset($_POST['create_table'])) {
    create_t($row_num['num_t'], $_POST['num_of_members']);
    $_POST['create_table'] = null;
}
```

но возникла проблема: выбрал кол-во строк, нажал кнопку, echo возвращает "1" но создаеться только одна строка.. помогите найти ошибку или дайте идею как еще можно ето сделать)

Comment: начните с того, чтобы не добавлять строки в БД, используя цикл, когда это можно сделать одним запросом. Ознакомьтесь с синтаксисом команды `INSERT`.

Comment: но надо добавить количество строко которое укажет пользователь

Comment: знаю вставить можно 
    query("INSERT INTO `mybase`.`lottery_$num` (`num`) VALUES ('$i'),('$x'),('$y'),('$z');"); но я не знаю сколько именно строк введет пользователь